# How to reduce legend box width in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'd like to reduce a legend box width.
[image]

My code

```
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data =russia,  aes(long, lat, group = group), fill = "grey")+ 
  geom_point(data = prisons, aes(x=lon, y = lat, color=type))+
  theme(legend.justification=c(1,0), legend.position=c(1,0), 
        legend.box.background = element_rect(color="red",size=1), 
        legend.key.size = unit(0.2, "cm"))
```

How to do this?

Comment: Looking at the plot, it makes me wonder why this is happening. Are you sure your levels for type are "clean" (have no extra spaces at the end)? If not, you could use `trimws` to snip whitespaces from front and back of the string.

Comment: @ Roman Luštrik I tried this but I don't have extra white spaces at the end

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `legend.margin` argument.

`theme(legend.margin=margin(0,0,0,0))`

Margin let’s you specify top, **right**, bottom and left margin, respectively.